# Are there any costs to create smart contracts in Solidity?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

Good afternoon,

I'm studying a little bit about blockchain and Solidity, researching some videos I found an ethereum IDE called Remix, where we can create smart contracts and put them on the network.

I would like to know if creating contracts in Solidity and placing them on the Ethereum network generates any monetary costs? If it generates any costs, can I create my own network with Solidity so as not to generate costs?

Best regards. Flavio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to know if creating contracts in Solidity and placing them on the Ethereum network generates any monetary costs?

When you deploy a smart contract onto the Ethereum blockchain, you must pay a small fee since you're storing bytes of code on the chain.

The cost of deployment depends on 4 things:

1. The amount of bytecode in the contract
2. The flat fee of 32k gas (create opcode)
3. The transaction data sent when deploying the contract
4. Any code run before the creation of the contract (in the constructor)

> If it generates any costs, can I create my own network with Solidity so as not to generate costs?

You can look into creating your own testnet, look into [Ganache](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache).